# Network card rtw_8821ce repeatedly stops working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

Hi I have a lenovo ideapad l3340 with installed ubuntu 20.04 with network card rtw 8821ce. I read that a lot of people have trouble installing drivers but that was never my case, which is a bit different.

So after turning on the laptop everything is fine and after about 30 minutes to 5 hours my network card stops responding. Nothing, not even localhost is working, and resetting network manager and so on doesn't help. Only thing which works is to restart my laptop but this is pretty annoying because every day this is happening 3-10 times.

I have had this laptop for about one year and a few months ago I had this problem for about a week and then it stopped happening. I don't know if it was one of thousands of things that I tried or it was pure luck but now it started to happen again and I don't know what to do.

Also after I restart my laptop I often get some errors, everytime a little bit different but something like `[3211.826282] rtw_8821ce 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0` despite this, after restart everything is fine.

Comment: Try this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260589

Comment: And, of course, there's a UEFI update (maybe) that already addressed the issue.

Comment: Try 22.04 from flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

try
echo "options 8821ce wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8821ce.conf
and reboot